# Combining images to make a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uibutton

If I have one png which is basically a button image with nothing inside of it:

```
----------------
|              |
----------------
```

How do I lay an image onto that, to make the image part of the button, like:

```
----------------
|    (image)   |
----------------
```

(I could just lay a UIImageView on top, but that would not inherit button properties, like going dark when pressed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the image that is basically a button as the backgroundImage of the UIButton, and use the other image as the image of the UIButton.

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Foo"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```